# What algorithms do solvers such as CPLEX and Gurobi use to solve the convex mixed integer nonlinear problems?

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

What algorithms do solvers such as CPLEX and Gurobi use to solve the convex mixed integer nonlinear problems?  (I guess them are using the branch and bound algorithm). Anyone knows this?

Comment: have you considered reading the manual?